# how to convert a set in python into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to convert a Set into a Dictionary. I am struggling to find a way to make this possible. Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Input : {'1438789225', '1438789230'}

Output : {'1438789225':1, '1438789230':2}
```

Comment: Where did `1` and `2` come from?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Its like a counter from '1 to n' for the number of values present in the set.

Comment: I agree with @Tiger. The problem is, you're adding previously non-existant information in your example. The simple answer to this is to iterate over the set, and insert each element into the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` to generate a value starting from 0 and counting upward for each item in the dictionary, and then assign it in a comprehension:

```
input_set = {'1438789225', '1438789230'}
output_dict = {item:val for val,item in enumerate(input_set)}
```

Or a traditional loop:

```
output_dict = {}
for val,item in enumerate(input_set):
    output_dict[item] = val
```

If you want it to start from 1 instead of 0, use `item:val+1` for the first snippet and `output_dict[item] = val+1` for the second snippet.

That said, this dictionary would be pretty much the same as a `list`:

```
output = list(input_set)
```

Comment: and if the value isn't actually important: `{ item:1 for item in input_set }`

Comment: @WilCooley - that wouldn't be much of a counter from 1 to n, though.

Comment: no, it won't; it's not clear to me (even after your attempt at clarification) if the counter is actually important or if that was an extraneous detail.

Comment: to start counting from 1 the easiest way is using `enumerate(input_set, start=1)`

Answer (score 2):

My one-liner:

```
output = dict(zip(input_set, range(1, len(s) + 1)))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) mixes two lists (or sets) element by element (`l1[0] + l2[0] + l1[1] + l2[1] + ...`).

We're feeding it two things:

- the input_set
- a list from 1 to the length of the set + 1 (since you specified you wanted to count from 1 onwards, not from 0)

The output is a list of tuples like `[('1438789225', 1), ('1438789230', 2)]` which can be turned into a dict simply by feeding it to the dict constructor... `dict`.

But like TigerhawkT3 said, I can hardly find a use for such a dictionary. But if you have your motives there you have another way of doing it. If you take away anything from this post let it be the existence of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0):

My Python is pretty rusty, but this should do it:

```
def indexedDict(oldSet):
    dic = {}
    for elem,n in zip(oldSet, range(len(oldSet)):
        dic[elem] = n

    return dic
```

If I wrote anything illegal, tell me and I'll fix it. I don't have an interpreter handy.

Basically, I'm just zipping the list with a range object (basically a continuous list of numbers, but more efficient), then using the resulting tuples.
Id got with Tiger's answer, this is basically a more naive version of his.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't recommend masking the built-in function `set()`. 2. `zip()` with a `range()` is basically `enumerate()`. 3. it's `len(set)`, not `set.size()`.

Comment: I didn't even know `set` was an already existing name, thanks. And thanks. I forgot about python's way of managing lengths.

Comment: Oh, and `range()` starts from 0 by default, so you can just do `range(len(oldSet))`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 -_- Thanks. I shouldn't try to answer questions for languages that I haven't used in years.

Comment: The solution is to use Python more. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Unfortunately, all the programming courses past the introductory level use Java or C++, so I'm stuck with those if I want to remain fluent for my courses :/. Python definitely reminds me of a simpler time though.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way of doing this is by iterating on the set, and populating the result dictionary element by element, using a counter as dictionary key:

```
def setToIndexedDict(s):
    counter = 1
    result = dict()

    for element in s:
        result[element] = counter #adding new element to dictionary
        counter += 1 #incrementing dictionary key

    return result
```